# routing in golang failing

Tags: go, routes

So I created a simple static site using go.

https://play.golang.org/p/s3XOqLj2SM

When you hit the root directory, the index.html page loads just fine including all the assets.

If you try to navigate to one of the other pages, the html does not load. I get a 404 error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you have all the template files correctly named in the `templates` folder? For example if you want to navigate to `/contact` you should have a `templates/contact.html` file.

Comment: I create directory `templates` with `index.html`, `about.html` and `contact.html` and your code work (but I have to edit your code, because you haven't function `profile` and `resume`, I change first to `about`, and delete second)

Comment: Root directory is called staticSite. 
Inside staticSite, two directories. 
Public for css file, and templates. 
Inside templates directory are all html files.
In root directory is main.go

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the mix up, there was a typo in the links within the html files.
If anyone else has this issue, it wasn't with the go side of things. It was within the HTML files not linking to the correct routes.